# amazon linux 2 yum missing update (AWS Security Center)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum, amazon-linux-2

AWS security advisory https://alas.aws.amazon.com/AL2/ALAS-2021-1674.html is causing my security scan to fail. The advice is to `yum update httpd` to install httpd-2.4.48-2.amzn2.x86_64. However when I do this AWS yum repo only has an old version of this package (httpd-2.4.46-2.amzn2.x86_64).

```
yum update httpd
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No packages marked for update


yum install httpd
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, kernel-livepatch, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                                                                                                                                           | 3.7 kB  00:00:00     
Package httpd-2.4.46-2.amzn2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

This is a brand new unmodified AWS linux 2 instance. I have tried everything I could find online (making sure I can access yum repo and clearing cache)

Can anyone else using amazon linux 2 see this new package? (2.4.48) or even better have any suggestions how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worked it out - AWS Elastic Beanstalk in all their wisdom append a "-$guid" to the YUM repo list on an instance, which must be stuck in their CDN as was returning an out of date package list. I have resolved via:

```
sed 's/-$guid//g' /etc/yum.repos.d/amzn2-core.repo -i
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS security advisory Link mention that we have to do "yum update httpd". If it still does not work I would say we have to update yum repo.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't resolve the issue. When you say "update yum repo" I'm currently pointed at AWS's eu-west-1 repo that they manage, I suspect that repo is out of date, can i force to update?